# Ionic create new application getting stuck

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am creating new application in Ionic framework with command

> ionic start firstapp blank

when it reaches to following step

> Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android?

It asks for the Cordova integration. I am making choice Yes but after that it is getting stuck and not moving ahead. I tried clearing cache but it has not resolved my issue. Please let me know if someone has faced this issue.

[image: Ionic version and create project step screenshot]

Comment: You can try to type in `y` instead of `Yes`. Not sure if it affects

Comment: It asks for you need to add Cordova platforms for android and ios. type y.

Comment: After typing Y it hangs forever and not moving ahead. I mentioned that in my OP that I am making choice Yes and after that it is not moving ahead. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm having the exact same issue.

As soon as you create a new app it will ask you if you want to target Android and IOS, Selecting y/n does not work and typing Yes or No does not work either.

I've cleared the Cache using npm cache clean --force and I'm still getting stuck here.

After uninstalling Node.js, npm, Ionic and Cordova I reinstalled everything again as the official documentation shows, but my terminal is still freezing. I've also tried Different terminals such as Windows power shell, CMD and Visual Studio Code.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/

I'm running Windows 10 with build 1709, Not sure if the issue could be related to this?

Ionic Version - 3.20.0
Cordova Version - 8.0.0
Node Version - 10.5.0

EDIT: - I've resolved the issue.

I uninstalled my Node.Js Version 10.5.0. I then Installed Node.Js LTS Which is version 8.11.3 and it worked great.

Here's the link:

https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-x64.msi

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Alexander it worked! Initially I thought my company's firewall might be blocking but then I tried solution mentioned by you and it worked.

Comment: You're more than welcome, I was having the same issue so I'm glad i could have helped!

Comment: Confirming this is also the solution for Ionic 3.20.1

Comment: Same for me, just updated NodeJS to the last LTS version and it has worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Worked. Not sure why you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but another solution I found was to run with the --no-interactive

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found to start a blank IONIC project.

`Ionic start FirstApp blank --cordova`